# Ungrouping of values into multiple lists

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

Given is a list with (possibly) non-unique elements.

My goal is to split this list into multiple lists, in sum containing the same elements, but separated in a way that no sublist contains each element value more than once.

A few examples to show the supposed result:

```
[1, 2, 2] -> [[1, 2], [2]]

[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4] -> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [4]]

[4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5] ->
[[4, 1, 3, 2, 5], [4, 1, 2, 5], [4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2], [4, 1]]
```

The order of the elements is not important. The fact that is it preserved is just a side-effect of my current implementation, but not needed. So the following would also be valid:

```
[1, 2, 2] -> [[2, 1], [2]]
```

My current implementation looks as follows:

```
fun <T> ungroupDuplicateValues(values: List<T>): List<List<T>> {
    val result: MutableList<List<T>> = mutableListOf()
    var counts = values.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().toMutableMap()
    while (counts.isNotEmpty()) {
        val newCounts: MutableMap<T, Int> = mutableMapOf()
        val subResult: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()
        for ((value, count) in counts) {
            subResult.add(value)
            if (count > 1) {
                newCounts[value] = counts.getValue(value) - 1
            }
        }
        result.add(subResult)
        counts = newCounts
    }
    return result
}
```

It works, but feels kind of clumsy. Is there a more elegant/idiomatic (maybe functional) solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Played a bit with it... how do you like the following?

```
fun <T> ungroupDuplicateValues(values: List<T>): List<List<T>> {
  val countPerValue = values.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
  val maxCount = countPerValue.map { it.value }.max() ?: 0
  return (1..maxCount).map { index ->
    countPerValue.filterValues { it >= index }
        .map { it.key }
  }
}
```

Complexity (in regards to O-notation) should be similar to yours...

Or the following variant using `tailrec`:

```
fun <T> ungroupDuplicateValues(values: List<T>) = ungroupDuplicateValues(values.toMutableList())

private tailrec fun <T> ungroupDuplicateValues(remainingValues : MutableList<T>, newValues : MutableList<List<T>> = mutableListOf()) : List<List<T>> {
  val values = remainingValues.distinct()
  newValues.add(values)
  values.forEach { remainingValues.remove(it) }
  return if (remainingValues.isEmpty()) newValues
         else ungroupDuplicateValues(remainingValues, newValues)
}
```

But don't ask me about the O-notation here. `tailrec` should be optimized, but as I still use a `forEach { remove }` it will probably still be `O(n²)`.

If you rather prefer a direct assigned function (of the first shown solution), maybe the following is also ok for you:

```
fun <T> ungroupDuplicateValues(values: List<T>) =
  values.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().let { countPerValue ->
    (countPerValue.map { it.value }.max() ?: 0).let { maxCount ->
      (1..maxCount).map { index ->
        countPerValue.filterValues { it >= index }
            .map { it.key }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nice, a lot more terse. But do I understand correctly, that it raises the time complexity to `O(n²)`?

Comment: It is probably as complex as yours... I think yours was already `O(n²)`... your `while` is hit `m` times (`m < n`) which will translate to `O(m*n)` which is basically `O(n²)`...

Comment: adapted it slightly... still didn't do anything to improve the complexity itself ;-)

Comment: added variant with `tailrec` ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like your first solution the most. And disregarding the `toMutableMap` call, which might be `O(n*log(n))` in case of a map based on trees instead of hashing), the complexity of my solution should be `O(n)`. Example 1: The list `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` will cause 5 iterations in the outer loop, with 1 in the inner loop each. Example 2: The list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] will cause 1 outer iteration with 5 inner iterations. And I think your solution does the same. So my initial `O(n²)` statement was wrong. :)

Comment: It's been a while since I last calculated O-complexities, but ... I am pretty sure that none of the solutions shown has `O(n)` complexity.... regarding `O(n*log(n))` maybe... but if yours has `O(n*log(n))` the first variant probably has it too... regarding the recursive one which is translated effectively into a `while(true)`... don't know ;-)